# HTML input fields are skipped when clicked on (only webkit on android)

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, webkit

When text field is activated via webkit on android, the field is skipped immediately and there is no chance to edit the field. I would like to be able to edit the field upon click.

**Code**

The JS/CSS files are too large to be uploaded, please see pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/6L6rzXYd)

**Video demonstration**

I recorded a video on my android phone. Please see the error recreated [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DM_pGdpHbQQ) in video.

Appreciate your help on this. Thank you!

*Error in the video was created on OnePlus 3, running Android 6.0.1. Ran it on iPhone and desktop with no problems

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].*

Comment: Make sure that you understand that the problem is not "Android" but [webkit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998074/what-is-the-engine-of-android-native-browser)

Comment: Sorry am quite new to stackoverflow and programming in general. Edited the question. Thank you.

Comment: @Roy , not a problem at all. I just want to make sure that you can narrow down your search and save time. Also, would you be able to post a screencap? i cannot see your video load.

Comment: @JGallardo Screencap [here](http://imgur.com/a/deJf8). Thanks.